# mySQL outfile & permissions under Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mysql

I know there are already several postings on the stackexchange sites about Linux permissions, but I can't find the answer to my problem.

I'm working on my own laptop (no web server or anything) with mySQL.  I'm using mySQL directly from the console client.  Frequently, I want to run a query and save the results elsewhere for further work in LibreOffice or whatever.  I use `select ... into outfile 'path+file';`.  Even though I'm logged in as myself, I'm unable to save the output file into my `~/Downloads/` directory, which I'm using as a temp directory.  I understand that the mySQL server is running under a special user, not me.  Since I'm the only real user on here, I executed `sudo chmod 7777 ~/Downloads`, and see it now shows `drwsrwsrwt`. After the chmod, I restated the server.  However, I still get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access Denied...` if I try to output into this folder when logged into mySQL as me. Logged in as root, I get `ERROR 1 (HY0000): Can't create/write to file ...` when I run the same command.

Hence, I'm stuck logging in as root, exporting my data to `/tmp/`, then doing `sudo cp` from another terminal to get my data.  Any suggestions on what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing and got similar errors. Then I realized my path was not exactly correct. Gave it the correct path all was well. If you are literally using '~/Downloads' for the path I expect this is not correct. More likely it's something like '~drew/Downloads'. You could also try using the full path to your downloads directory.

TD

Comment: Thanks TD, but no dice.  Even if I enter the full /home/ahowe42/Downloads path, it still can't access it.